# Why can't I merge these 2 faces together?

Tags: edit-mode, faces

Blender beginner here. I want to merge 2 selected faces seen on this imag but when I do that with F then the result will be on image below. Dissolving faces doesn't do anything in this case.

[image]

This is what it looks like before trying to add them together

[image]

[image]

Comment: Faces can't have holes inside them. All holes need to be connected to another edge/vertex by at least 2 edges. That second result is prefectly normal. Though you usually connect them to an existing vertex, like the corners of the big face, so you are not adding unneccesary geometry

Comment: Please use Blender's built-in Window > Save Screenshot menu to produce your images. As it stands it's difficult to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/3d_view/precision_drawing_tools/holes_in_faces.html